# Custom cell image deforms when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell for my `UITableView` ; that custom cell comes from a class that extends `UITableViewCell`. 
There is only a .xib where i crated the actual cell, and the links to these items in the .h. 
I'm not using the .m, it's only the autogenerated `awakeFromNib` and `setSelected:selected:animated` in there.

When i create my cell in the `cellForRow` method, it's all fine, it appears correctly on the screen.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCellTableViewCell";
    CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [self.tbUpcomingEvents dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    tmp = [_eventList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lbDescription.text = tmp.description;
    cell.lbTitle.text = tmp.title;

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tmp.type.typeImage];

    cell.lbTimeStart.text = [[[timeFormatter stringFromDate:tmp.startTime] stringByAppendingString:@" - "]stringByAppendingString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:tmp.startDate]];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
```

My issue is the following : when I start scrolling the tableview, the NEW cells are messed up, specifically the image. It simply gets bigger/wider and (obviously) deformed. I don't really know what caused it or how to fix it.

The cell is associated with the reuse identifier from the `cellForRow` method and the custom class in the .xib file. The `UITableView` has nothing in particular (and has no other link than the storyboard -> .h, delegate, datasource)

Any clue?

Comment: try to disable autolayout if it is enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my issue. In this specific case, my imageView in my customCell.h was called "imageView". Which is a reserved named and, i guess, created conflicts at (some?) points in the creation of the cells.

I don't know the why's, but i know what fixed the issue. Now i've simply put another property name for my image and i'm golden ;)

Comment: I get the same problem in swift. Solved by change outlet name of image variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code:

```
cell.lbDescription.text = tmp.description;
cell.lbTitle.text = tmp.title;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tmp.type.typeImage];
cell.lbTimeStart.text = [[[timeFormatter stringFromDate:tmp.startTime] stringByAppendingString:@" - "]stringByAppendingString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:tmp.startDate]];
```

from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to `willDisplayCell` method.

The idea is to make `UITableViewCell`s templates in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but to fill cells with particular values in `tableView:willDisplayCellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: It didnt solve the issue. I kind of notice that the scrolling problem happens when i scroll " fast ". It really apperas to be random and i can't figure out when/why it happens.

That being said, i notice the difference of display with the willDisplayCell because they are squary (and mine are round) so your method did get called, but SOME cells are still deformed. After scrolling for a while the cells stop changing and keep their problematic/normal state depending on the luck of the day.

Comment: @Zil just try. From docs: `You should fetch a previously created cell object that is marked for reuse by sending a dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: message to tableView`. This means, you copy old cells to show them in new index paths. Also: `A table view sends tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed`. I never have problems with images on cells when I use this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

uncheck autoresize subviews in interface builder

[image]